# Observable of BehaviorSubject keeps notifying unsubscribed Subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

There is a service used to read initial persisted values - "*settings*" and provide them via observable "*settings$*" to subscribers - components. Several components use the "*settings$*" observable to retrieve the initial persisted values and further exchange updated values among themselves. For that the BehaviorSubject is implemented in the service. All works well here.

```
@Injectable()
export class SettingsService implements OnInit {

  settingsBS; 
  settings$: Observable<SettingsI>;

  init() {
    this.settingsBS = new BehaviorSubject<SettingsI>(defaultSettings);
    this.settings$ = this.settingsBS.asObservable();
    ...
    let s: SettingsI;
    this.loadPersistedSettings(s);
                       // notify subscribers about the 
                       // loaded persisted settings 
                       // and pass these settings to them
    this.notifySubscribers(s);
    ...
  }
                      // this function is also used by components
                      // to pass new/updated settings to subscribers
  public notifySubscribers(s: SettingsI) {
    this.settingsBS.next(s);
  }
  ...
}
```

One component also needs the initial persisted data but needs no further notifications about the further updates in "settings". So, it initially subscribes for getting the initial persisted data and then it unsubscribes to avoid getting any further updates - like this.

```
constructor(private settingsService: SettingsService, ...) { ... }

ngOnInit() {
  const settingsSubscription = this.settingsService.settings$.subscribe(o => 
  {
      merge(this.persistedSettings, o);
      ...
  });
  ...
  settingsSubscription.unsubscribe;
}
```

However, the subscription remains alive despite the:

```
settingsSubscription.unsubscribe;
```

The section inside the subscription:
      {
          merge(this.persistedSettings, o);
          ...
      });

is always being triggered when any component uses the service and the function:

```
settingsService.notifySubscribers(s)
```

The questions are:

1. How come the: *"settingsSubscription.unsubscribe;"*
   does not cancel the subscription ?
2. How can this be resolved ?

Answer (score 5):

`unsubscribe` it is a method not a property so you need to use `()` which will become:

```
.unsubscribe();
```

If the goal is to subscribe and get only the initial persisted data, one can use: `take(1)`

```
this.settingsService.settings$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(...)
```

It will unsubscribe automatically after getting the first data.

Comment: Great quick observation of the mistake - of missing (). I wonder why I got no warning from the IDE or compiler.

Comment: It is neither a compilation error nor a runtime one. Simply put it is not an error, but it is not what you want to do